# Terminal that supports all SGR ANSI escape codes

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm searching for a terminal for linux, which can display all SGR (Select Graphic Rendition) ANSI escape codes from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes. I would like best if there would be a debian package for the terminal. gnome-terminal and xterm for example do not support italic (3).

Comment: Following http://superuser.com/questions/204743/terminal-that-supports-the-ansi-italic-escape-code gnome terminal >= 3.6.1 does indeed support italics

Comment: Oh, i have version 3.4.1.1, thats the stable debian version. but the SGR ANSI escape codes from 0 to 65 were defined since 1991.

Comment: Some of them are supported but not all (unfortunately). I guess this was because GUIs got deployed more and more after 1991.. Also I'm unsure if the used console font limits the number of working SGR codes.. Need to investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any that support *all* SGR codes.  Recent-enough xterm (since [patch #305](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_305)) and gnome-terminal support italics, if that is all that is needed.